# How to use wget http status codes in an if else statement to take an action based on the status code

Tags: bash, http

I'm writing a script that is downloading a bunch of files,  I'm using wget to download the file and I want to echo back to the terminal custom status messages for each file based on 3 scenarios:

1. Files downloaded successfully (HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
2. Files did not change from the one locally (HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified)
3. Anything else is a failed download

I'm able to get the status code and use awk to isolate just the status code number(200, 304, etc)
I have the following to pull out the HTTP status:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -NS http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip 2>&1 | grep "HTTP/" | awk '{print $2}'

if [ $? = 200 ]; then
echo "File downloaded
"
if [ $? = 304 ]; then
echo "File not modified from local copy"
else
    echo "Something went wrong"
    exit 1
fi
```

But this just prints the http status code back to the terminal, and always returns that last else statement.

> laptop:~$ ./test.sh 
> 304 
> Something went wrong

How do I send the output to run through an if else statement?

Comment: usually you should use elif to go through in once, else you break up the if else chain

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the HTTP status code to the standard output but your code compares a return code from `wget`, not a value printed to standard output. If there is no error then `wget` returns `0`.

Comment: right - how can I print the HTTP status code to standard output and use in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Your script needs to capture the output of the first command. There may be a more elegant approach, but the basic form:

```
wget_result="$(wget -NS http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip 2>&1|grep "HTTP/"|awk '{print $2}')"

if [ $wget_result = 200 ]; then
echo "File downloaded
"
if [ $wget_result = 304 ]; then
echo "File not modified from local copy"
else
    echo "Something went wrong"
    exit 1
fi
```